# Userid variable issue

Tags: windows-10, batch, batch-file, script, user

I got 2 commands issue if let say my userid = testing computer it will grab testing instead of testing computer. If my userid = testing i have no issue with it. Anyone can assist how can I fix this to have the full userid. userid without space works smoothly userid with space it seems to capture only the testing how can i make it capture both variable together?

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ('qwinsta /server:%COMPUTERNAME% ^| findstr "console"') do set userid=%%j

SET /P userid=Please Enter UserID:                   
IF "%userid%"=="" GOTO Error
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `qwinsta /server:%COMPUTERNAME%` to the question.

Comment: Hi, i added in my post

Comment: Try to make the `set` command into: `set "userid=%%j"`.

Comment: i try set command set "userid=%%j" but it revert with testing only not testing computer

Comment: Using punctuation more generously would make your question way easier to understand - and thus people more likely to answer.

Comment: @gronostaj hi edited my post thanks for remind.. it is my first time posting here sorry for the inconvenient  cause

Comment: This advice is not limited to this site. People are more likely to talk to you when they understand what you're talking about ;) These are nice too: `,` `"`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is that `for` splits by space. You'd need it to split by "more than one space", which `for` doesn't do.

You can workaround this restriction by replacing every two spaces with a unique character (`@` in my example) and then split by that introduced char:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('qwinsta /server:%COMPUTERNAME%^|findstr /bc:" console "') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=@" %%b in ("!line:  =@!") do set "userid=%%b"
)
if "%userid:~0,1%" == " " set "userid=%userid:~1%"
if "%userid:~-1%" == " " set "userid=%userid:~0,-1%"
echo "%userid%"
```

The variable may contain one leading and/or one trailing space (formerly unpaired spaces), which you'll have to remove (the two `if` commands).